# Java regex modifying the lookaround assertions

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
String str = "(varA=0.1;varB=0.2;varC<0.3;varD>=0.4)<?0.1>(varA=1.1;varB=1.2;varC<1.3;varD>=1.4)";
```

and I want to split it into

```
(varA=0.1;varB=0.2;varC<0.3;varD>=0.4)
<?0.1>
(varA=1.1;varB=1.2;varC<1.3;varD>=1.4)
```

I have tried

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=>)|(?=<)");
```

But it didn't work. 
Any suggestion? Thanks!
But it pops error

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\))(?=<)|(?<=>)(?=\\()");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL9tZ1/1)

**Output:**

```
(varA=0.1;varB=0.2;varC<0.3;varD>=0.4)
<?0.1>
(varA=1.1;varB=1.2;varC<1.3;varD>=1.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String line = "(varA=0.1;varB=0.2;varC<0.3;varD>=0.4)<?0.1>(varA=1.1;varB=1.2;varC<1.3;varD>=1.4)";

  String pattern = "(\\(.*\\))(<.*?>)(.*)";
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
  }
}
```